# I declared a type in Range<int> but still got compilation error on "does not name a type" after read all the answer from similar questions

Tags: c++

I am very new to C++ and I did search previous answers for my questions "x does not name a type" from StackOverflow. However, I still couldn't find how my code violating any causing this compilation error.

My environment is Ubuntu c++-8 and I ran on the terminal as g++-8 -pedantic -std=c++14 -Wall -weffc++ -Wextra Range.c++ -o Range

I got "Range does not name a type" and 'b' was not declared in this scope. However, I did declare 'b' and 'e' as an int of iterator Range template type. Please kindly help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;
```

template 
class RangeIterator {
    public:
        using iterator_category = input_iterator_tag;
        using value_type        = T;
        using difference_type   = ptrdiff_t;
        using pointer           = T*;
        using reference         = T&;

```
private:
    T _v;

public:
    RangeIterator (const T& v) :
            _v (v)
        {}

    bool operator == (const RangeIterator& rhs) const {
        return (_v == rhs._v);}

    bool operator != (const RangeIterator& rhs) const {
        return !(*this == rhs);}

    const T& operator * () const {
        return _v;}

    RangeIterator& operator ++ () {
        ++_v;
        return *this;}

void test1(){
    const RangeIterator<int> x(2,2);
    const RangeIterator<int>::iterator b = begin(x);
    const RangeIterator<int>::iterator e = end(x);
    assert(b == e);
  }

  int main(){
   test1();
   return 0;}
```

Comment: What is this thing called `Range`? It's certainly not something declared in any of those header files.

Comment: You’ll probably need to `#include` the header file with the definition of `Range`.

Comment: Almost everything in C++ needs to be declared prior to use. So you need to make `Range` template declaration (and probably definition) available by including corresponding header file.

Comment: Neil Butterworth, Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Dietmar Kühl, Thank you. I got this code from a completed code example. Obviously, I should still define a header file for Range.

Comment: VTT, Thank, I got this example from a completed code example, it aimed to demonstrate range iterator. However, I am too new to know range should be defined in header file.

Answer (score 3):

you seem to forgotten to include the header file that contains the declaration of the template class named `Range`.

if you already have your header file. you just have to include it in your headers list

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <iterator>
#include "Range.h" //this is an example.  it could be named differely on your end.
```

Your Range.h file should contain the class declaration for `Range`  which would look something like this.

```
template<typename Type>
class Range
{
public:
    Range(int a, int b);
    //...
    //...
};
```

Comment: Yu could change `int` to `Type` to maybe be a closer guess to what the actual file looks like, but either way, the missing include is likely it.